# Character IO in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();

    while(c != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }


}
```

In the above code I understand that putchar(c) prints the first character of the string stored in variable c. However I don't understand how it could print the entire string when putchar(c) is placed inside this while loop. How does the condition c != EOF increment the string index of c? How is c=getchar() outside while loop is different from  the one in the body of the loop?

Comment: There is no *entire string*. `getchar()` receives a single `char` at a time; the loop outputs that `char` and then retrieves another one. (`c` should be declared as `char`, because the function is `getchar()`, not `getint()`, BTW.)

Comment: @KenWhite no, `getchar()` returns an `int` because `EOF` is an `int` and you need to check for it.

Comment: @KenWhite,   the function: `getchar()` returns an 'int', so the code is correct.

Comment: Yep. Ignore the portion of my comment in (). My C is rusty. :-)

Comment: Note: the loop will not end until the user enters (depending on the OS) a <ctrl>d --or-- <ctrl>z character

Comment: Note: this line: `void main()`  there are two valid and one optional ways to declare the main() function.   All the ways of declaring the main() function have a return type of 'int'    Suggest, when compiling, enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: You might like to add a `flush(stdout)` right after the call to `putchar()` and get enlightened. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`c != EOF` does *not* increment the string index of `c`. `stdin` is the input-buffer. You are reading from `stdin` (with `getchar`) and writing to `stdout` (with `putchar`). When you call `getchar()`, a single-character is read from `stdin`, and the *file-position-indicator* for `stdin` is *advanced-by-one* (to the next character).

When you read a character from `stdin` (advancing to the next character) and write one character to `stdout` *within a loop*, you consume all characters in `stdin` one-by-one until you reach `EOF` for `stdin` (i.e. you have read all the characters available in the input-buffer)

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour that "it prints the entire string" after you hit Enter is because `stdout` (standard output) is buffered. If it would not be buffered, each character you type will be printed immediately (duplicating your input).

Comment: 1) more than likely 'echo' is on, so each char is immediately shown on the terminal.  2) when an output is made, followed by an input (stdout/stdin) the output buffer is flushed before the input is performed. 3) the loop also echo's any newline char (from the user hitting the 'return/enter' key) because the call to getchar() will retrieve anything in the input stream, include the 'enter' key.   However, Note: *the program sees nothing until the user presses the 'enter/return' key*

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, but that's because the terminal input is also line-buffered, independent of what `stdin` gets.

Comment: In reality, terminal I/O is '`cooked`  If you want to have the application receive the characters without the user having to press the `enter` key, then change the terminal I/O mode to `raw`.   But then the application will have to handle all control keys and editing keys and etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually c just stores a single character. The program reads some input one character at a time, and prints it out one character at a time, until there is no more input.

I've added some comments to the code so you can see what it's doing:

```
    int c;
    c = getchar(); //get a new character from input and store in c.
   while(c != EOF) // while the current character  is not an End Of File
   {
        putchar(c); // print the current character 
         c = getchar(); // fetch the next character  from input
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two I/O operations in your program:  (1) `c = getchar()`, which reads the next character from standard input and stores it in `c`, and (2) `putchar(c)`, which writes character `c` to standard output.  If invoked from a terminal window with no redirection, then standard input (stdin) and standard output (stdout) will just be your terminal window (in which case you will need to enter the appropriate EOF character for your system.  However, either may be redirected to/from a file or a pipe.

Note that the "classic" way to write this is to embed the `getchar` assignment in the `while` test:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

This is functionally identical to your version but with only a single place where `getchar` is called.